# Presigned Url multipart part upload always returns 403

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am receiving error while uploading multipart data in chunks in S3 bucket using presigned url in Swift.

**My code is** : -

```
func AWSS3UploadMultipartData(data: Data, strVideoName : String, strContentType: String , _ completion: @escaping s3CompletionHandler)
 {
          let multipartRequest = AWSS3CreateMultipartUploadRequest()
          multipartRequest?.key = strVideoName
            multipartRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
             multipartRequest?.contentType = strContentType
           let awsService = AWSS3.default()
         awsService.createMultipartUpload(multipartRequest!) { (multipartUploadOutput, error) in
                      self.multipartUploadId = multipartUploadOutput?.uploadId
                    self.completedPartsInfo = AWSS3CompletedMultipartUpload()
                  self.uploadAllParts()
         }        
 }
 func uploadAllParts ()
    {
           repeat {
                       // get the length of the chunk
                        let thisChunkSize = xxxxx;

                       // get the chunk data
                        let chunk = xxxxxx

                       //saving the file to Documents Directory in  chunkURL

                       self.uploadAWSPart(uploadDict: dict, fileURL: chunkURL!, mediaName : fileName, 
                         awsPartNumber: offset)

                       offset += thisChunkSize;

        } while (offset < length);
}

 func uploadAWSPart(uploadDict : [String : Any], fileURL : URL, mediaName : String, awsPartNumber : Int)
    {

        let getPreSignedURLRequest = AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest()
        getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
        getPreSignedURLRequest.key = mediaName
         getPreSignedURLRequest.httpMethod = AWSHTTPMethod.PUT;

   getPreSignedURLRequest.expires =  Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 36 * 60 * 60);
 getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = contentType
             getPreSignedURLRequest.setValue(self.multipartUploadId, forRequestParameter: "uploadId")
        getPreSignedURLRequest.setValue(String(awsPartNumber), forRequestParameter: "partNumber")

           let MD5 = self.md5File(url: fileURL)
            getPreSignedURLRequest.contentMD5 = MD5
          let presignedTask = 
            AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(getPreSignedURLRequest)

presignedTask.continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                if let presignedURL = task.result
                {

                      ///This is the response of presignedURL:-

                        *******************************************************
                          https://bucketName.s3-ap-south- 
                       1.amazonaws.com/c9e407127756360d54b85a469b728e0d_1534190164.75355.mp4? 
                        X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz- 
                         Credential=AKIAIBZJLCO6SJCZZ7YQ%2F20180813%2Fap-south- 
                          1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180813T195604Z&X-Amz- 
                         Expires=129599&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent- 
 type%3Bhost&uploadId=RSjis.pARzI3IPESBYvxWhcY5ta_ybURr7fnUK4fKBVTTS9cMjyVfG4nmJVAu 
                     O.cQ.K7mSAPpLzLwW7CElIUyFaXnMmCTrr7A2p7r1KG79Q-&partNumber=0&X-Amz- 
                   Signature=f2d555fd64f80e1ba86c8ed0b0eb63a1b184304fcbfde6a91198163df2a67900

                   *********************************************************                

                    self.startUploadForPresignedURL (presignedURL as URL, chunkURL: fileURL, md5 : 

                     MD5!, MediaName : mediaName, strContentType : contentType, awsPartNumber: 
                          awsPartNumber)
                }
                return nil
            })
    }


func startUploadForPresignedURL (_ presignedURL:URL, chunkURL: URL,  md5 : String, MediaName : String, strContentType : String,  awsPartNumber: Int)
    {

       let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: presignedURL)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData        
        request.timeoutInterval =  Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 36 * 60 * 60).timeIntervalSinceNow 
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.setValue("public-read", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-acl")
        request.setValue(MediaName, forHTTPHeaderField: "filename")
        request.setValue(strContentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue(self.md5File(url: chunkURL), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-MD5")         
        let uploadTask = self.session?.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, fromFile: chunkURL)
        uploadTask?.taskDescription = String(awsPartNumber)
        uploadTask?.resume()
    }

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("\(#function)")
        if (error != nil) {
            print("didCompleteWithError error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
        else {
            print("didCompleteWithError success: \(String(describing: task.response))")
        }
    }
```

**The error is**: -

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c4432b60> { URL: https://bucketName.s3-ap-Region.amazonaws.com/xxxxx.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIBZJLCO6SJCZZ7YQ%2F20180812%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180812T190423Z&X-Amz-Expires=129599&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bcontent-type%3Bhost&uploadId=rtRmP_xSnCVBURpnAnUFSbN5JLy9h11yDyDxtrTmMc9oAFMfIi95hX82bbupk497uIoHtC5tYXezK2fLcHb7fh_aR1win8eiAYCcKakmxvo-&partNumber=17825792&X-Amz-Signature=39d31e9f41371242099164702d329d8e81e6f4b16fabba0ed29507ceabc05130 } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/xml"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 12 Aug 2018 19:04:30 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        AmazonS3
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "x-amz-id-2" =     (
        "0bmVCpzxQZRVYUSeEKIMrxq0rMd9Ts5eYne7timdoH++ThvvNJo+Wjq9Jhckx/AP1fNiaPhVhqQ="
    );
    "x-amz-request-id" =     (
        C171A1AE06D092EF
    );
} })
```

I have tried different options, but none worked. I have also tried multipart stream upload using Alamofire, but the same error is comming. I also posted this issue to aws-sdk-ios in github, but they also have no proper answer till now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you by any chance manage to solve this without using AWS Amplify?!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the TransferUtility provided in the AWS Mobile iOS SDK instead of rolling your own implementation to do multipart uploads.

That said, looking at your code, one thing that jumped out at me was that you are setting the x-amz-acl in the request to upload the part. That header is not allowed for a part ( See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html for a list of all allowed headers when uploading a part) and is likely causing the server to reject it as an invalid request. The x-amz-acl header should only be included in the createMultiPart request. 
Remove that header from the part upload and that should resolve the 403 error.

See the code from line 1315 (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/7c6c287f5cf0313ef042d34f18b5f82b27298a30/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferUtility.m#L1315) for how the TransferUtility creates a presigned URL for a part and uploads it using a NSURLSessionUploadTask.

Also, look at code starting from line 131 (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/7c6c287f5cf0313ef042d34f18b5f82b27298a30/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferUtility%2BHeaderHelper.m#L131) for the details of how the TransferUtility looks for certain headers and strips them out of the part upload.

Comment: @cbommas Thanks for your response.
But I didn't understand what is wrong with my approach. As because AWSTransferUtility doesn't support transfers that take longer than 50 minutes. So, I am using this.

Comment: @Aviru No, there is nothing wrong with your approach, I was merely making a suggestion that you could use the TransferUtility to avoid taking on the complexity of working with the multipart API.

Answer (score 0):

So I've used AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest() to get a PUT presignedURL and used this using URLSession.upload, and it all works fine. Use the same exact parameters using Alamofire.upload, always get a signature error. Wanted to use something other than AWS upload since you can't control retries or timeouts with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else sees this: The problem here is is not on the iOS side but the configuration on AWS that needs to be set accordingly so that `Content-Type` is accepted (as set by URLSession's `upload(:fromFile)` automatically). As of 2023:

> It turns out that your region (eu-west-1) supports signature version 2 and 4 and it makes tricky when used with multipart upload and presigned URLs. You can find more information about signature version 4 on link [2] and check regions with supported signature versions on link [3].
> I suggest specifying signature version 4 and virtual host for addresing style. Virtual host style address is recommended since it has more benefits than path style address.  Please take a look at link [4].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3-core

[4] https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/s3.html